# sort array with special characters in php

Tags: php, sorting, collation

I have an array I'm trying to asort using php. The problem is that the array has accented characters in it and needs to be sorted using "french" rules.

```
 cote < côte < coté < côté
```

I've tried many things, like using php collators, but I get the following error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Collator' not found
```

I've also tried to set locale but it didn't do anything so I'm not sure I was doing it right, or if I need to isntall the locale. I'm a little confused.

I'm using PHP 5.2.4 if that helps. If I use asort without anything, it puts all the words with accented characters at the end.

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't qualify this as an answer, but it's worth while to check out: http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/php/Sorting_With_Foreign_Languages.htm

Comment: `cote < côte < coté < côté` woah... what sort of rule is that?!

Comment: @Anthony, I'll check it out.
@nickf Haha. Basically an accented letter is in between the unaccented letter and the next one. a < à < b.

Comment: that doesn't explain `côte < coté < côté`

Comment: You're right. Haha that's messed up. I got that from the php website so either it's wrong or I have it wrong. I thought it should be cote <  coté < côte < côté. Quite confusing either way...

Comment: I get the same error and I am using php 5.3.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up installing the French language pack to my server and using the following :

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'fr_CA.utf8');
asort($array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

Works for my needs...

Comment: Just used this. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The [Collator class](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) is part of PHP's [internationalization extension](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php), which comes standard with PHP 5.3

Since you have 5.2.4 you'll need to [install this extension](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php) in order to make use of its classes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just upgrade to 5.3? Also I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: If upgrading to 5.3 is a option then I definitely say "go for it".  Then you can start using the cool new language features like closures and late static binding.

Answer (score 0):

for those who are in Brasil:

setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "ptb");

Pratical Example:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
return strcmp($a["first_name"], $b["first_name"]);} $docs = array(
1 => array(
    'first_name' => 'Márcia Amanda',
    'crm' => 4321,
    'job' => 'Médica',
    'sex' => 'f'
),
2 => array(
    'first_name' => 'Pedro Alexandre',
    'crm' => 6789,
    'job' => 'Veterinário',
    'sex' => 'm'
),
3 => array(
    'first_name' => 'Lívia Pereira',
    'crm' => 8765,
    'job' => 'Obstetra',
    'sex' => 'f'
));  usort($docs, "cmp", SORT_LOCALE_STRING);

                            $qtas_pessoas = count($docs);

                            $j=1;

                            while (list($key, $value) = each($docs)) {

                            if ($j==1) echo "<div class='wrapper indent-bottom7-1'>";

                            $dr='';
                            if ($value["sex"]=='m') $dr='Dr.';
                            else $dr='Dra.';

                            echo "
                            <div class='grid_4 alpha'>
                                <h6 class='p2'>$dr ".$value["first_name"]."<br/>CRM ".$value["crm"]."</h6>
                                ".$value["job"]."
                            </div>\n
                            ";
                           $j++;
                           if ($j>$qtas_pessoas) {
                               echo "</div>";
                               break; // TEMOS APENAS X PESSOAS...
                           }
                           // quebrar sempre de 3 em 3
                           if ($j % 3 == 1) echo "</div><div class='wrapper indent-bottom7-1'>"; 
                            }
```

by Luy Angelino