# How to sort values with special chars in array?

Tags: php, asort

First, I set the proper locale to spanish:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
```

This array holds a list of languages which must be reordered alphabetically.

```
$lang['ar'] = 'árabe';
$lang['fr'] = 'francés';
$lang['de'] = 'alemán';
```

So I do this:

```
asort($lang,SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

The final result is:

- alemán
- francés
- **árabe**

...and it should be:

- **árabe**
- alemán
- francés

The asort() function is sending the á character to the bottom of the ordered list. How can I avoid this issue? Thanks!

**Solution** [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10649560/338840) by @Sbls

```
function compareASCII($a, $b) {
    $at = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $a);
    $bt = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $b);
    return strcmp($at, $bt);
}
uasort($lang, 'compareASCII');
```

Comment: wouldnt `ksort` work for you? I sorts the keys instead of the values.

Comment: @Sbls That's won't work in my case. I have several language packs, the keys always stay the same, but the values won't. I always need to order by value.

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649473/sort-an-array-with-special-characters-in-php

Can you work with that question thread?

Comment: One thing I see, is that you are setting the values of `$lang`, but sorting `$list['translate']`, is that the same array?

Comment: AlexSiri: It wouldn't sort at all. Maybe a typo. 

@andufo: The whole thing works for me though. Well, árabe comes after alemán for me. But it doesn't come last.

Comment: @AlexSiri yes, same array, ill correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution linked by @Sbls in comments

```
function compareASCII($a, $b) {
    $at = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $a);
    $bt = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $b);
    return strcmp($at, $bt);
}
uasort($lang, 'compareASCII');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Collator::asort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/collator.asort.php) from the `intl` module:

```
<?php
$collator = collator_create('es_ES');
$collator->asort($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the comparison checks the multibyte value of the character, and `á` in that case is probably greater than `z`, so it will show afterwards. If you want a comparison that does not take that into account, I see two possibilites:

1. Sort using [uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) and create your own comparison function.
2. Generate a mapping from the ascii version of your strings, to the real one, and sort on the keys.