# Sort multidimensional array with special characters in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, that I'm sorting alphabetically, but problem is, with danish special characters æ ø å. They should be sorted in that order, but is not returned in that order.

This is my array (part of is removed)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Pater
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Allan

        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Ø test

        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Å test

        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Æ test

        )
)
```

I'm using this function to sort it

```
uasort($sorted_region, function($a, $b) {
    $retval = $a['Name'] <=> $b['Name'];
    return $retval;
});
```

Anyone know, how to sort it, so I get æ ø å in the right order?

I've seen some using e.g.

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'da_DK.utf8');
asort($array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

But I'm not sure how to implement this in a multidimensional array.

Thanks for any help! :-)

Comment: Is the DK locale installed?

Comment: does this letters, would be sorted with the English alphabets too?

Answer (score 2):

Actually this seems to work

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'da_DK.utf8');

usort($sorted_region, function($a, $b) {
    return strcoll($a['Name'], $b['Name']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924776/how-to-sort-values-with-special-chars-in-array)

with this solution, linked by @Sbls in comments on that page. it would need to be modified for your charset but it should work.

```
function compareASCII($a, $b) {
  $at = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $a);
  $bt = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $b);
  return strcmp($at, $bt);
}
uasort($lang, 'compareASCII');
```

Comment: 1) I don't think will work with multidimentional arrays. 2) Please don't copy/paste answer, flag for duplicates instead.

Comment: will do, apologies.