# how to sort folders first with scandir and using usort

Tags: php, sorting, usort, scandir

For a filemanagement, I use `create_function` to sort folders(directories) first and then files. But it seems that `create_function` is deprecated in php 7.2.

So how can I use the `usort` below correctly?

```
 $files = array_diff( scandir($dir), array(".", "..", "tmp") );

 usort ($files, create_function ('$a,$b', '
  return    is_dir ($a)
    ? (is_dir ($b) ? strnatcasecmp ($a, $b) : -1)
    : (is_dir ($b) ? 1 : (
        strcasecmp (pathinfo ($a, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), pathinfo ($b, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 0
        ? strnatcasecmp ($a, $b)
        : strcasecmp (pathinfo ($a, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), pathinfo ($b, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
    ))
  ;
'));
```

Comment: Use an anonymous function instead of `create_function`.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: @mud you can compare arrays of conditions using the spaceship operator.  Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56086562/2943403

Comment: This is working fine: `usort ($files, function ($a,$b) {
 return is_dir ($a)
  ? (is_dir ($b) ? strnatcasecmp ($a, $b) : -1)
  : (is_dir ($b) ? 1 : (
   strcasecmp (pathinfo ($a, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), pathinfo ($b, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 0
   ? strnatcasecmp ($a, $b)
   : strcasecmp (pathinfo ($a, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), pathinfo ($b, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
  ))
 ;
});`