# PHP sort array with special characters

Tags: php, sorting, laravel-5

I know this was asked many times, but still I can't find bullet proof solution.

Here is my array which needs to be sorted alphabetically.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sl_SI.utf8');

$a = [
   'č' => [...],  
   'a' => [...],
   'š' => [...], 
   'u' => [...] 
]
```

How can I sort it by keys?

Comment: [It gives output this](https://eval.in/990861), What your desire output ?

Comment: I want it sorted by keys [a => [], č => [], š => [], u => []]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken reference from this example:-[Sort an array with special characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10649560/4248328)

***Explanation:-***

1. Get array keys using `array_keys()` method
2. Sort keys based on `iconv()` AND `strcmp()` functions
3. Iterated over the sorted key array and get their corresponding value from initial array.Save this key value pair to your resultant array

Do like below:-

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sl_SI.utf8');

$a = [
   'č' => [12],  
   'a' => [23],
   'š' => [45], 
   'u' => [56] 
];


$index_array = array_keys($a);

function compareASCII($a, $b) {
    $at = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $a);
    $bt = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $b);
    return strcmp($at, $bt);
}

uasort($index_array, 'compareASCII');

$final_array = [];
foreach($index_array as $index_arr){

$final_array[$index_arr] = $a[$index_arr];
}

print_r($final_array);
```

***Output:-*** https://eval.in/990872

***Reference:-***

[iconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

[strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

[uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

Comment: What about [`sort($index_array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)? Why is a comparison using `iconv()` and `strcmp()` better? :-)

Comment: This works! Also now I tried with  ksort($array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING), which works too, but only on linux environment.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer  `sort($index_array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);?` not worked:-https://eval.in/990875

Comment: @Tim  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 4):

Use `strcoll()`.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sl_SI.utf8');
// setlocale(LC_ALL,"cs_CZ.UTF-8"); //for Czech characters etc.
uksort($a, 'strcoll');
```

You can use usort for sorting multidimensional arrays by value this way:

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sl_SI.utf8');
 // setlocale(LC_ALL,"cs_CZ.UTF-8"); //for Czech characters etc.
 usort($posts, function($a, $b) {
    return strcoll($a["post_title"], $b["post_title"]);
 });
```

or for objects:

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sl_SI.utf8');
 // setlocale(LC_ALL,"cs_CZ.UTF-8"); //for Czech characters etc.
 usort($posts, function($a, $b) {
    return strcoll($a->post_title, $b->post_title);
 });
```