# ksort associative array problem with 4 of Persian characters

Tags: php, sorting, farsi, ksort

I'm working with an associative array with key value which the keys are Persian strings and the problem is when i use ksort to sort the array. the problem is sorting process has no effect on four specific character and put them in the end of sorted array.
here is those 4 characters:

گ
چ
پ
ژ

I think this happened because 4 chars are not exists in Arabic letters.
here is an example

$main_array = array("محمد"=>55,"علی"=>67,"رضا"=>90,"گلاب"=>34)
after ksort it must show this as result:
رضا,علی,گلاب,محمد
but the ksort result this:
رضا,علی,محمد,گلاب

```php
Array
(
    [فولاد امیر کبیر] =&gt; ۶۵۵
    [شرکت فولاد کیان ابهر] =&gt; ۶۶۵
    [فولاد آریا ذوب] =&gt; ۶۵۶
    [گروه صنعتی فولاد یزد] =&gt; ۶۵۱
    [فولاد قائم رازی] =&gt; ۶۶۴
    [فولاد سیادن ابهر] =&gt; ۶۶۳
    [مجتمع فولاد البرز غرب] =&gt; ۶۴۹
    [شرکت فولاد سپهر ایرانیان] =&gt; ۶۶۱
    [فولاد کیان کاشان] =&gt; ۶۵۷
    [فولاد شاهرود] =&gt; ۶۵۴
    [فولاد آناهیتا گیلان] =&gt; ۶۵۹
    [نورد آریان فولاد] =&gt; ۶۴۸
    [فولاد میانه] =&gt; ۶۵۸
    [فولاد بافق یزد] =&gt; ۶۶۲
    [فولاد قزوین] =&gt; ۶۶۰
    [پرشین فولاد آریا] =&gt; ۶۵۲
    [فولاد نیشابور] =&gt; ۶۵۳
    [فولاد کویر کاشان] =&gt; ۶۵۰
    [ذوب آهن اصفهان] =&gt; ۶۴۷
)


//here is the example which ksort working properly by english chars
$myarray = array(
"reza"=>35,
"mohamad"=>56,
"nima"=>45,
"ali"=>76,
);
ksort($myarray);
print_r($myarray);

//here is the example which ksort not working properly by persian chars
$mypersianarray = array(
"علی"=>35,
"گلاب"=>56,
"رضا"=>45,
"محمد"=>76,
);
ksort($myarray);
print_r($mypersianarray);

//output
Array ( [علی] => 35 [گلاب] => 56 [رضا] => 45 [محمد] => 76 )
//which is wrong and گلاب goes at end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an array with special characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649473/sort-an-array-with-special-characters-in-php)

Comment: No.I tried that but not working.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you explain how that other solution did not work?

Comment: The other solution not work and do not consider گ چ پ ژ chars and put them at the end of sorted array

Comment: Is there any solution?zbee